# .NET Thread-safe call to the Window.WindowStyle Property

Tags: .net, multithreading

I am currently making an application in which I have two threads running, and one often needs to set the Window.WindowStyle property, but I get an error when I try to do so (because my call isn't thread-safe). I am already aware of how to use the InvokeRequired method of solving this but, when I type this.WindowStyle.InvokeRequired, Viusal Studio says InvokeRequired isn't a valid property.

How can I fix this?

Please note that my application is a WPF app, not a Form. I would prefer answers to be in C# terminology, as I don't know VB.NET very well.

Thanks for all your help!

EDIT: Ok, so this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess() seems to have fixed the initial problem, but I am now getting the same error when I attempt to actually invoke in the "if" statement. Any suggestions?

Comment: Shouldn't you use Window.InvokeRequired?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you will have more success if you use `SynchronizationContext` here instead of the older `ISynchronizeInvoke` interface.

Somewhere in the startup of your WPF application, you should create a synchronization context, something like this:

```
SynchronizationContext SyncContext = new DispatcherSynchronizationContext();
```

This code will create a synchronization context using the current dispatcher, so you would probably call this during initialization of your main window, after the dispatcher has started.

Next you use the `Send` or `Post` methods to marshal your code onto the GUI thread:

```
SyncContext.Send(delegate(object obj) {
    // set main window style here, for example:
    MainWindow.WindowStyle = WindowStyle.SingleBorderWindow;
}, null);
```

There is a good article on synchronization contexts at code project: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/threads/SynchronizationContext.aspx, but it is specific to Windows Forms.

Comment: What would I put in the // ... set main window style here area?

Comment: I modified the code example above to give you a bit of an idea. Basically, you put anything you want to run on the main GUI thread in there. In your case you are setting a property on the main window.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check `if (this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())`

Comment: What do i use instead of SetTextCallback and this.Invoke?

Comment: @user788532: `this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(...))`